# Absolute positioned element gets hidden on screen resize

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">

  <div class="navbar-inner">

      <div class="container">

        <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
            <span class="page-title" data-bind="text: router.activeItem().title"></span>

            <ul class="nav" data-bind="foreach: router.visibleRoutes">
              <li data-bind="css: { active: isActive }" class="navLi">
                <a data-bind="attr: { href: hash }, text: name" href="#"></a>
              </li>
            </ul>

       </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</nav>

span.page-title {
    font-size: 32px;
    color:white;
    position:absolute;
    left:-330px;
    top:-5px;
}
```

I am using twitter bootstrap for css in my web application. I am trying to show the page title on the navigation bar for which I have used absolute positioning. When I resize my browser window, the page title becomes invisible.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use default Bootstrap markup for page title (`.navbar-brand` class).

Here is link to blank template page: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/

and here is [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6rvyL/)